# How to do autoremove when executing apt-get remove?

Tags: apt, updates

I wanted to remove un-used packages together when doing `apt-get remove -y XX` , but how ? And the solution should not affect `apticron auto system updates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -y XX
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following command:

> `sudo apt-get autoremove`

If you want to combine it with the command that removes a package, use the following syntax:

> `sudo apt-get remove -y XX ; sudo apt-get autoremove`